# No done event fired on ngx-uploader

Tags: angular5, ngx-uploader

**done** is not getting fired after the upload is completed for ngx-uploader

This is the log:

```
{type: "addedToQueue", file: {…}}
file-upload.component.ts:29 {type: "allAddedToQueue"}
file-upload.component.ts:29 {type: "start", file: {…}}
file-upload.component.ts:29 {type: "uploading", file: {…}}
```

No done event after this.
The server responds with 200 OK status.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a conflicting library you used with your angular app, that's why it's not triggering the done status.